# Is the limit of a sequence of characteristic functions of probability measures a characteristic function of a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Given a sequence of probability measure $P_n$ on $\mathbb R$ with the Boreal sigma algebra, define $f_n = \int e^{ixt}dp_n$, and suppose that $f_n \to f$ for some $f$ bounded measurable, is it true that there exists some $p$ such that $f = \int e^{ixt}dp$?

My intuition tells me that this is false, but I cannot come up with an example. The example that I tried: Let $p_n$ be the Gaussian with mean $0$, variance $\frac{1}{n^2}$, then the characteristic function converges to the constant $1$. However, $1$ is the characteristic function of some dirac delta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having Gaussian with decreasing variance, let $p_n$ be Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $n$.  This gives the counterexample you are looking for.  In general the continuity theorem states that if the limiting function $f$ is continuous, then there exists such a $p$, but not otherwise.